# Implement a counter as a flowfile atribute in Nifi

Tags: apache-nifi

Using Nifi, I want to handle errors of a processor.

If the processor sends the flowfile to the failure link, I want to send it back x times to the processor that failed to process it.

For that, I wanted to implement a counter in the flowfiles attributes. However, I am facing two issues

- How can I check if the flowfile contains the `counter` attribute ?
- How to increase the `counter` attribute if it exists ?

So far, I have the following flow:

[image: current flow]

And I am stuck on the "Update Counter" processor. I do not understand how I can achieve this.

The attribute `counter` does not exist when the flowfile first comes in. I want to check if it exists, if not, ad it to the flow file. When it comes later during execution, if it exists, I want to increment it. How is that possible ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this expression.

```
${counter:replaceNull(0):plus(1)}
```

If the `counter` attribute does not exist, this will create the value with `1` and if the `counter` attribute exist, it will be updated +1.

Answer (score 2):

[**UpdateCounter**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46924082/how-to-use-value-of-a-counter-in-nifi) processor updates counter and used only for monitoring feature, we can't access them using expression language.

- To check counter value click on Top right corner hamburger menu > counters

> **How to check or add to flowfile?**

Use **`UpdateAttribute`** processor and add new property called:

*counter*

```
${counter:isNull():not():ifElse('${counter:plus(1)}','${literal("0")}')}
```

With the above expression we are checking is the counter attribute notnull

- True then incrementing the attribute value by 1.
- False adding the attribute `counter` with value as 0

---

Take a look into [this](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/NiFi-best-practices-for-error-handling/m-p/123721) thread regards to similar usecase and you can also use [updateattribute](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/Apache-Nifi-Problem-with-getStateValue/td-p/239004) processor storing the state locally option too.

Comment: Yup ! this is the correct way of doing it ... thanks Shu !